# Firebase updating single field

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already have a large JSON file which I will be uploading to firebase. Sample format is

```
{
  "ImpList": [
    {
      "email": "NA",
      "name": "NA"
    },

    {
      "email": "NA1",
      "name": "NA1"
    }

  ]
}
```

For testing purpose, I have uploaded this to firebase and my structure looks like 
[image]

Now I need to update the value of email "email1" to "email2". I am able to successfully fetch the data and display it in the sample app. I am not using any firebase auth so basically anybody can update the content. I have seen this example [Firebase updating value for a field in a child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934347/firebase-updating-value-for-a-field-in-a-child) but in my case, I do not have any key.

Answer (score 2):

Try do this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("teste-2df21").child("ImpList").child("Implist").child("0").child("email");

        myRef.setValue("email2").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

            }

        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
```